# I'm having trouble running this program

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, casting, user-input

```
# Tipper Program
# User enters the bill total and the program computes two amounts,
# a 15 percent tip and a 20 percent tip

print("\t\t\t **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **")

print("\n\t\t\t\t    Tip Calculator")

print("\n\t\t\t **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **")

bill = input("\nPlease enter your restaurant's bill total: ")

tip_15 = bill * 0.15

tip_20 = bill * 0.20

float(print("\n\nA 15% tip for this bill comes out to ", tip_15))
float(print("\nA 20% tip for this bill comes out to ", tip_20))


input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

The app keeps closing after I enter the number for the bill total. Any recommendations to solve this issue?

Comment: You're casting your print statement to a float? remove `float()` from 2nd and 3rd last line

Comment: A general tip: run the program from `cmd.exe` (assuming Windows). If you just double-click on it, it will exit immediately on an error, and you won't be able to read the helpful error message.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Did you miss the `input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")` at the very end?

Comment: @martineau that won't execute if an error occurs before that line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask the user for input you need to cast this value to a float before you multiply it by 0.15 and 0.20

```
bill = float(input("\nPlease enter your restaurant's bill total: "))
```

and also your last 2 lines should not be cast to a float

```
print("\n\nA 15% tip for this bill comes out to: ", tip_15)
print("\nA 20% tip for this bill comes out to: ", tip_20)
```

Comment: Probably wanna do:

    print("\n\nA 15% tip for this bill comes out to ".format(tip_15))